# How do you write euler in C, what's wrong with my code?

Tags: c

1. I made a code of is_coprime function and euler function. but the results come out 0. what is the problem?
2. you don't need to touch the main function part.
3. you don't need to add anything else. only the is_coprime, euler function part can be modified.

---

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int is_prime(int m, int n) {

  int r;

  while (n > 0) {

    r = m % n;
    m = n;
    n = r;

    if (m == 1)
      break;
  }
}

int euler(int n) {

  int i;
  int sum = 0;

  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {

    if (is_prime(i, n) == 1)
      sum += 1;
  }

  return sum;
}


main() {

  int i;
  for (i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {

    printf("euler(%d) = %d\n", i, euler(i));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] and tell us what output you get and what output you expect. Read this: [ask]

Comment: This really feels like a homework or some other kind of assignment. Read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Hint: What does `is_prime()` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your <is_prime> function is not returning anything.
put a suitable "return" part for it.